# Creating a dynamic array with Class Pointers

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I'm having trouble with a specific part of an assignment asking to create a function that would take and store numbers in an array of Numbers (the class).

```
class Number {
public:
    // Make a number with value 0
    Number();
    // Make a number with value val
    Number(int val);
protected:
    string value;
}

Number::Number() {
    value = "0";
}

Number::Number(int val) {
    value = to_string(val);
}

/*
* Ask user how many numbers they want entered and store the numbers in an array of Numbers.
* Set length parameter to # of numbers entered and return the array pointer to the caller.
*/

Number* getNumbersFromUser(int& length) {
    cout << "How many number would you like to enter?";
    cin >> length;
    Number *numbers = new Number[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cout << "Enter the number value ";
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    int length;
    Number* numbers = getNumbersFromUser(length);
    reverseAllNumbers(numbers, length);
    cout << "All the numbers in reverse are:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    numbers[i].print();
    }
    delete[] numbers;
    cout<<endl;
```

It seems like it's specifically requested that I use dynamic arrays, but I don't understand how I can have the user input things of type Number, as the compiler is saying it's not allowed. Please ignore the `reverseAllNumbers` function, I believe I have that one figured out.

EDIT: I understand there's a lot of wierd things with my code. The use of string and the necessity to use an array instead of a vector are all constraints that were placed on my assignment.

Comment: Why are you storing the number as a `std::string`?  Are you trying to implement some kind of big-integer class to handle values greater than 64 bits?  If not, then you should be using `int`, `long long int`, or `__int64` instead of `std::string`.

Comment: It was the constraints set for the assignment that I use string. I understand that it would be a lot easier without that constraint.

Comment: For future reference, when you ask about something that has constraints attached to it, please specify what those constraints actually are, so people don't waste their time trying to tell you how to do things that do not fit within your constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a global `operator>>` for your `Numbers` class, eg:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &strm, Number &n)
{
    int value;
    strm >> value; // or however you need to read the value...
    n = Number(value);
    return strm;
}
```

Or:

```
class Number {
    //...
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &strm, Number &n);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &strm, Number &n)
{
    strm >> n.value; // or however you need to read the value...
    return strm;
}
```

Usually when you override the global streaming operators, you should implement member methods to handle the actual streaming, and then call those methods in the global operators.  This allows the class to decide how best to stream itself:

```
class Number {
    //...
    void readFrom(std::istream &strm);
};

void Number::readFrom(std::istream &strm)
{
    strm >> value; // or however you need to read the value...
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &strm, Number &n)
{
    n.readFrom(strm);
    return strm;
}
```

If you are not allowed to define a custom `operator>>`, you can still use the `readFrom()` approach, at least:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    std::cout << "Enter the number value ";
    numbers[i].readFrom(std::cin);
}
```

Comment: The assignment specifically asked that I use an array. I appreciate the help, but would there possibly be another method? The use of global operator is a topic that has not yet been covered.

Comment: If the assignment *requires* a raw array, then so be it.  But that does not change what I said about implementing a custom `operator>>` for your class to handle streaming. If you have not covered operator overloading yet, you can still use the `readFrom()` method I showed: `numbers[i].readFrom(cin);`

Answer (score -2):

You will probably have to return `number` at the end of function `getNumbersFromUser` to avoid memory leakage.
Secondly, the line `cin >> number[i]` means that you are taking input in a variable of type `Number` which is not allowed. It is only allowed for primitive data type (int, char double etc.) or some built in objects like strings. To take input in your own defined data type, you will have to overload stream extraction operator `>>` or you can write a member function that takes input in class data member(s) and call that function. For example if your function is like

```
void Number::takeInput () {
      cin >> val; 
}
```

Now go in function and write `number[i].takeInput()` instead of `cin >> number[i]`.